# Bad file descriptor exception when using file.length

Tags: java

i am getting the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
   at gnu.java.nio.channels.FileChannelImpl.size(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.length(libgcj.so.10)
   at ServerSendFile.getAndSetDataFromFile(ServerSendFile.java:738)
   at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:613)
   at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:212)
   at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)
   at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
   at Server.run(Server.java:292)
```

Here I had `Server.java` which runs the `ServerSendFile` as a thread for every comming request to `Server.java`

the purpose of `ServerSendFile` is it will send data reading from file

There is a lot of code ,I only pasted small snapshot it is causing at line `rafLogFile.length();`

```
 try
      {
        long fileSize = rafLogFile.length();

        //if the file size may size is zero then, return to fetch the data next innterval
        if(fileSize == 0)
        {
          return true;
        }  
      }
      catch(IOException eio)
      {
        cmonLog.stackTraceLog(className, "getAndSetDataFromFile", "", "", "Exception caught in retriving length of log file = " + lastFile.getAbsolutePath(), eio);
      }
```

Comment: Is the file closed anywhere before the program reaches the above code?

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue with jdk/jre version.

Just check if the code is compiled and running with same jdk/jre version